# How to to store multi-dimensional form data?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a form where fields get added via JavaScript. This is fairly easy to store without a bunch of extra JS code (for deleting and reordering) by using arrayed names for fields.

```
<input type="text" name="product[]" />
```

The problem comes when I need a multi-dimensional arrayed list of form data.

```
order
  request_date
  product[]
  quantity[]
    warehouse1
    warehouse2
    etc...
```

Basically, each order has the order data, multiple products, and each product line item can be pulled from one or more warehouses. If the line item's order quantity is 100, and the first choice warehouse only has 50 units, they will need to select a secondary warehouse to get the second 50 units from...

I am trying to get this all onto one page possibly with JS popups to select between the different warehouses.

The problem is when I try to think of a good way to send this info to the server.

I would like to use the arrayed line item info, but cannot figure out how to send the multiple warehouses per line item back to the server. Should I just do something like comma separated values in a hidden field (populated by the JS warehouse selection popup)? Is there a better way? Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

If it matters, the backend is PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use JSON? On the PHP end you'll end up with an array of elements for the nested arrays.

It sounds to me like you're either unaware of JSON (and with an SO rep of 3k, I can't believe that) or that you're unaware that you can pass JSON back to the server.

But for what you're describing, that sounds like a natural and perfect fit.

---

"stick that array element as an object onto the returned value"

```
var returnObject = { field1: "value", field2: "value" };
var buildArray = [];
$(specificSelector).each(function(){
  buildArray.push($(this).data('myKey'));
});
returnObject.field3 = buildArray;
```

- Note that this uses `.each` which is ugly and nasty. There are better ways to do this, if you want speed or cleanness. But this works.
- Note that I have not tested this fully, this was off the top of my head, for demonstration of concept.
- Note that I assume each object to be selected has a `.data` associated with it, of key `'myKey'`. You could instead iter over each cell in a table, or whatever. This is how *I* do it, and probably leads to bloated pages anyways. But when I append a row I attach the value as an object so I can do this sort of thing faster (faster to type that is)

Comment: i don't do a lot of in-depth JS. this would mean I would need to crawl the form data, format it into JSON, and send via AJAX right?

Comment: @dqhendricks You can just serialize it - see **[.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)**

Comment: @Tadeck serializing it will create a URL string. this still has the original problem of not easily having a multi-dimensional array server side.

Comment: @dqhendricks But it works - see [.post() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). It says: _data - A map or string that is sent to the server with the request_, so this means it is accepting serialized string as data also, like in the fourth example on the mentioned documentation page: `$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());`. Does it work now?

Comment: it looks as though i will end up storing the warehouse data in a hidden field as a JSON string which I can decode on the PHP side. am also taking the advice of sending the whole form as a serialized AJAX request so that I don't have to worry about repopulating field values in the case of a validation error. thanks guys.

Comment: @Tadeck I know that the URL serialized string can be sent, but read the original post. The problem lies in trying to create a dynamic multi-dimensional array, without having to name each newly created field a unique name.

Comment: @dqhendricks ... that's ... one way to do it. A completely AJAX request is another way. However, if this works for you, then yatta!

Comment: @jcolebrand how would you recommend? would you crawl the form and form it all into a JSON string? I'm suprise JQuery doesn't have a formToJSON or something.

Comment: and what do you mean "completely AJAX request"?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I would do. What I actually do is on each object, as I insert it into the DOM, I give it a class and attach .data to it. Then I grab all the elements of a given class, put the .data into an array, and stick that array element as an object onto the returned value. So pretty much what you said, but I try and make it more elegant. Hmmm, I don't have a sample I can point to to explain this, and I would need to answer this in the evening to give you an example in code.

Comment: As far as "completely AJAX request" I mean I wouldn't call the form's submit behavior.

Comment: I think I understand up until the "stick that array element as an object onto the returned value".

Comment: yeah, that's what i'm doing. I am using serialize and sending the form as an AJAX request, then redirect on success response.

Comment: I edited my answer to add that part about "stick that array element as an object onto the returned value". HTH

Comment: luckily for me, client side performance for this page is not much of an issue. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Send back as JSON.

```
order: {
    request_date: '07/06/2011',
    products: [
    {
        id: 1,
        quantity: 3,
        warehouses: [1]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        quantity: 4,
        warehouses: [1,2]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        quantity: 5,
        warehouses: [3]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<input name="order[product][]" value="" />
<input name="order[product][]" value="" />
<input name="order[product][]" value="" />
etc...
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a multi select box for all the warehouses. In case you also need to specify how many units per warehouse, then this doesn't work. You can do it like this:

```
<select name="order4quantity2warehouse">
  <option>Warehouse 1</option>
  <option>Warehouse 2</option>
</select>
<input name="order4quantity2warehouse-quantity" />
```

Then on the server size you decode $_POST to exact all the data into arrays. For example you can do this by looping over the keys of the $_POST and determining which pattern the key matches, e.g. order[number]quantity[number]warehouse, and then insert it into the appropriate place in your arrays.

Comment: No, do not go that way - you can pass arrays withing requests, even multi-dimensional ones. There is no need to complicate your life with such solutions. Sorry.